Usar ou não letras maiúsculas em "português brasileiro"?
Dúvida: "português brasileiro" ou "Português Brasileiro"? Deve-se ou não usar letras maiúsculas no início das palavras nesta expressão?

As minúsculas são preferidas e de uso mais comum, a menos que o termo esteja sendo usado como nome próprio de uma área, curso, etc.
Alguns exemplos do Ciberdúvidas:

Ele é estrangeiro, não percebe português.
Eu sou português, tu és brasileiro.
Tive boa nota no exame de Português.

Também o Acordo Ortográfico de 1990 determina, em sua "Base XIX – Das minúsculas e maiúsculas", o uso preferencial de minúsculas, com maiúsculas opcionais:

1.º A letra minúscula inicial é usada:
[...]
g) Nos nomes que designam domínios do saber, cursos e disciplinas (opcionalmente, também com maiúscula): português (ou Português), matemática (ou Matemática); línguas e literaturas modernas (ou Línguas e Literaturas Modernas).


Tipicamente disciplinas (matemática, física, biologia) são minúsculas pois são substantivos-comuns. Os nomes de cursos são maiúsculos pois são títulos de algo, substantivos-próprios (curso de Cálculo Infinitesimal, de Matemática I, de Biologia Molecular), como títulos de metragens são em maiúsculo (Tropa de Elite). Deve ser esse o raciocínio dessa tradição, imagino.
